# How to get Jetpack Compose's LazyGrid to render behind system bars?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to use Accompanist's System UI Controller library along with `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)` to render content behind a device's system UI.

I'd like to also use Jetpack Compose's inset paddings to add some pad the top of its LazyVerticalGrid, however the grid doesn't render behind the system bars if I give it a padding with `Modifier.statusBarsPadding()`.

```
@Composable
fun libraryScreen(navController: NavController) {
  Surface(
    color = Color.Magenta,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
  ) {
    Column(
      modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(
          horizontal = 10.dp
        )
    ) {
      LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(3),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
        modifier = Modifier
          .background(color = Color.Black)
//        .statusBarsPadding()
      ) {
        items(40) {
          albumCard("TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE ", "ARTIST ARTIST ARTIST ARTIST ARTIST ARTIST ARTIST ")
        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Comparison GIFs:

[Without any padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Css5.gif)

[With padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3u0G9.gif)

The same effect happens if I use a Box or Spacer above the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accompanist insets are deprecated use `WindowInsets` library.

```
  contentPadding = WindowInsets.systemBars
                .only(WindowInsetsSides.Vertical)
                // Add if you want to have extra padding with your grid, optional
                .add(
                    WindowInsets(left = 8.dp, right = 8.dp, top = 16.dp, bottom = 16.dp)
                )
                .asPaddingValues(),
```

add will add extra padding initial padding and will scroll below status bar and navigation bar when you scroll your grid

```
Surface(Modifier) {
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        contentPadding = WindowInsets.systemBars
            .only(WindowInsetsSides.Vertical)
            .add(
                WindowInsets(left = 8.dp, right = 8.dp, top = 16.dp, bottom = 16.dp)
            )
            .asPaddingValues(),
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(backgroundColor),
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(3),
        content = {
            items(snacks) { snack: Snack ->
                GridSnackCard(snack = snack)
            }
        }
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: Apologies, as I completely forgot! The padding I'm using is from the Compose library. Not Accompanists! I'll update the question.

Comment: If you use the `add` your `LazyVerticalGrid` have initial vertical padding but as you scroll it will show items behind statusbar. Added a gif to answer, hope i didn't get your question wrong.

Comment: Seems to work perfectly! Thank you! Marked as answer.